# Karma fails to open Opera on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run Karma with Opera and it does not work:

```
karma start --browsers Opera
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.10 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Opera
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Opera
```

And an alert appears in Opera it appears the message:

> Can't open user profile directory, because you lack sufficient
>   privileges. You might want to contact the administrator of this
>   machine.

How can I give the privileges to Karma to open Opera?

The other browsers like Safari or Firefox work well.

Answer (score 0):

The OSX Opera profile directory is:
"~/Library/Application Support/com.operasoftware.Opera", but this does not seem to be the issue.

The solution that seems to work is to ensure Opera is shut down completely before running the tests, as it may be a lock file issue.

It also helps to change the Opera startup prefrences to "On startup: Open the start page" rather than than "On startup: continue where I left off", that way you don't reopen a dozen tabs all containing your previous testrunner instances.